# Зачем нужны другие операторы если есть GoTo?

Tags: алгоритм, ооп, goto

Задался вопросом, а зачем нужны другие операторы и циклы если есть мощное ключевое слово GoTo?

GoTo можно заменить любой цикл, а так же GoTo дает простор для творчества, так как можно называть метки тем, что в голову взбретет .

Так же, все равно в конечно итоге красивый код превращается в последовательность GoTO на машинном языке.

На мой взгляд GoTo- это, что-то типа Базона Хигса, который считается частицей бога, а GoTo оператор машинного бога.

Comment: Но ведь красивее, удобнее и быстрее. Попробуйте на ассемблере написать мало-мальски сложное приложение.

Comment: Частица бога... А на деле всего лишь `jmp`. Одна из множества инструкций. Даже в машинном коде циклы организуют без goto;

Comment: "Зачем нужны языки программирования, когда есть ассемблер?" ... "Зачем нужен ассемблер, когда есть машинный код?"

Comment: Шикарно мыслите, завидую! Еще большие перспективы однако открываются, если использовать вместо GoTo русский аналог (у нас же тут по русски всё), при этом учитывая богатство языка оригинал разбивается как минимум на 3 - оператор ИдиТы, оператор ИдиНа, ну и супероператор - ИдиСка :-) Супероператор нужен для того чтобы выйти из других операторов :-)

Comment: Что может `goto`, без какого-никакого `if`?

Comment: goto - это вырожденная форма условного перехода. Поэтому, это никакой не б**о**зон (хотя может и б**а**зон).

Comment: @vp_arth на самом деле ещё и `jnz`, `jz`, `je`, `jge`... их много, по используемым флагам и положительности/отрицательности.

Comment: @D-side, это уже не `goto`, а `if() goto;`

Comment: @vp_arth если рассуждать так, то этим оператором можно сделать только бесконечный цикл, что явно противоречит вопросу :Р

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проблема в том, что код пишется не для компилятора, а для человека. Для ваших коллег и для вас самого через полгода.

Безумная мощь оператора `goto` оборачивается его слабой *выразительностью*. При помощи `goto` вы можете выразить именно что **всё**: и итерирование по списку, и проверку логического условия, и вызов подпрограммы, что угодно. Вам, видя оператор `goto`, для понимания текста придётся восстанавливать логику каждый раз самому. А это трата времени и мысленных усилий, которые приходится применять каждый раз, когда вам нужно понять, правильный ли код, или, ещё хуже, найти ошибку и исправить её.

Так что другие операторы в языках есть для людей, читающих и пытающихся понять логику программы. А компьютеру всё равно, он бы и с одним `goto` работал, железяка тупая.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не во всех языках есть этот оператор.
2. Бездумное использование приводи к коду который очень сложно понимать и поддерживать (спагетти-код).
3. Этот оператор плохо выражает намеренья программиста.

Comment: бездумное применение любого оператора/технологии всегда приводит к коду, который сложно понимать:). А намерения программиста goto выражает очень точно. Некоторые его используют направо и налево каждый день.

Comment: это не выражает намеренья, а выражает их отсутствие :)

Comment: вот если бы можно было писать просто `goto` и компилятор вставлял переход куда попало - тогда это было бы отсутствие намерения. Более того, куда попало им перейти нельзя.

Comment: что лучше выражает намеренья - if + goto или while?

Comment: и то, и другое. Все зависит от задачи. Некоторые симулируют while через if+goto, а некоторые используют идиому `do { break; } while(0);`, что бы только не писать goto (но при этом их код можно переписать, не используюя ни то, ни другое).

Comment: а если предположить, что в намерениях был цикл?

Comment: А почему тогда не написать for? :) В своих рассуждениях Вы считаете, что там мог быть только цикл, а там вариантов - вагон и тележка. И для каждой задачи нужен свой инструмент.

Comment: я не считаю, что там может быть только цикл, я считаю, что цикл лучше выражать циклом, а не if + goto.

Answer (score 1):

Это просто один из стилей 3-го поколения языков программирования. **По-моему**, возникший скорее для обучения новому мышлению, чем для реального выигрыша.

Языки второго поколения (Ассемблеры) без GoTO (JMP) просто не могли работать.
Переходные языки (Basic, Fortran) также нумеровали строки и использовали переходы.

Стиль "без goto" - всего лишь стиль, не более. Иногда алгоритмы с goto работают быстрее, т.к. в полной мере используют возможности самого процессора

- Оператор Бога... Что-то в этом есть. Именно идея абстрактной универсальной алгоритмической машины Эмиля Поста содержала что-то типа goto. Всего лишь 6 операций, позволяющих реализовать любой алгоритм... Эта одна из них

Comment: Кульминация: [URISC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URISC) (компьютер с одной инструкцией).