# Почему использование инструкции LABEL - это плохо?

Tags: javascript

Увидел один вопрос на тостере и попросил объяснение у автора ответа..
Тот кинул ссылку на MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label
Естественно что я ни гуру js  и я обратился как раз таки к гуру и тот мне дал другую ссылку и сказал что это родственник GOTO:https://habr.com/ru/articles/271131/
И так как я ни чего не понял, прошу объянить человеческим языком почему конструкция:

```
LABEL:
  statenent
```

ни есть хорошо...мне нужно теоретическое пояснение..плиз

Comment: вот уже разъясняли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627877/302603

Comment: @Ruslan вопрос не совсем про goto

Comment: Сам по себе label вообще ничего не значит. Плохо (с некоторых точек зрения) когда он используется для написания конструкций аналогичных goto. Про это ответ выше. Но, вообще говоря, это холиварная бездоказательная тема

Comment: А как через лейбл делать гоуту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это обычная конструкция языка, которая используется для быстрого перехода из одного места программы в другое с рядом ограничений (совместно с break и continue). Часто из глубокой вложенности циклов и обработки данных. Подобные операторы специально оставлены и в других языках, если они были плохими, их бы давно убрали.

Есть плохая практика использования и есть хорошая практика использования конструкций языка. В данном случае бездумное использование оператора в большинстве случаев усложняет чтение и изменение программы. Поэтому его стараются минимизировать в коде, чтобы не запутывать логику обработки.

Как уже было сказано, есть ряд случаев, когда он наоборот помогает, но использовать его надо обдуманно и с осторожностью. К примеру, выход из глубокой вложенности циклов при обходе трех-, четырех- и более мерных массивов.

```
first: for(let i = 0; i < dim.lenght; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < dim[i].lenght; j++) {
        for(let m = 0; m < dim[i][j].lenght; m++) {
            for(let n = 0; n < dim[i][j][m].lenght; n++) {
                if (dim[i][j][m][n].hasItems === false) 
                    continue first; // не нашли нужное, быстрый выход в продолжение первого цикла
                    
                // Дальнейшая обработка данных
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Попробуйте переписать это без label, скорее всего получите флаг, его установки и в довесок три проверки флага в каждой итерации, что выглядит так себе. Иногда логика обработки сложнее. Но такие задачи встречаются редко и потребность в том, что вам придется использовать метки, небольшая. Общая практика - если можете написать лучше без меток, лучше от них отказаться, чтобы не запутывать код.

P.S.> В отличие от label на goto ограничения более слабые и можно прыгать не только в пределах цикла. В любом случае для обоих случаев все вышесказанное остается в силе.

Answer (score -1):

GOTO это плохо, ибо оно рушит логику на вложенных уровнях логики, а тру-кодеры не мыслят себя без вложений. и чем выше вложенность уровней этой логики, тем хуже наличие GOTO в коде. на плоских конструкциях GOTO показывает себя отлично (Assembler из этого сделан - JMP называется). Про LABEL все вышесказанное верно

Comment: Про label выше ничего не сказано. Оно совершенно для другого

Comment: не важно для чего оно. Использовать его можно как GOTO, в этом контексте были вопрос и мой ответ

Comment: нельзя его использовать как готу.